# Spritekit acting weird with new images

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

So recently I added new images to the game I am creating. They are the same size and I have them appearing correctly. However, the physics body isn't the same or working properly. I haven't changed any code but did some testing on this line

```
     obs1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:obs1.size];
```

and changing the body of obs1.size to and size using CGSizeMake() isn't having an effect on the actual contact. It is either not there or way too big. I hope this makes sense. Looking for any help thanks.

The image size or file type hasn't changed so I don't know why the physics body is acting this way.

EDIT: I reverted back to before I added the new images and went through the steps again. I found the problem. By changing the scale of a a completely different image (say image1) the obstacle image's (image2) physic body changes automatically. I am going to resize the image before I even add it to the project and that should fix it.

Comment: If nothing has changed then perhaps the bug is somewhere else in your code. What else has changed? You are not providing much data to diagnose your issue. Be more specific.

Comment: I had everything working completely. All I did was change the images and now the physic bodies are all screwed up.

Comment: Perhaps your new images have an alpha border (invisible pixels) ?

Comment: I had thought that but I was send the psd file so I looked and it doesn't. I tried to adjust the physics body manually using CGSizeMake() and the height doesn't change no matter the value. However if it's 0 it will be non-existent

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using a PSD format graphic. Use PNG instead.

I am not sure how you are trying to manually size your physics body so just in case here is a sample:

```
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
```

or with a defined center use:

```
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100) center:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

Comment: I was doing that and using the png format. I just meant when looking at the psd format there was no alpha border

Comment: @bolencki13 - Then it's something you're not seeing. No pun intended. Start cutting out pieces of code until you get to nothing but bare bones (or less). Start from that point and see when you get the desired results. Then add pieces back step by step to see what has caused your issue.

Comment: I think I found the problem but I am not sure why image1's scale is affecting image2's physic body